# mod Distributive Law, factoring $\!\!\bmod\!\!:$ $\ ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I stumbled across this problem

> Find $\,10^{\large 5^{102}}$ modulo $35$, i.e. the remainder left after it is divided by $35$

Beginning, we try to find a simplification for $10$ to get:
$$10 \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 7\\ 10^2 \equiv 2 \text{ mod } 7 \\ 10^3 \equiv 6 \text{ mod } 7$$

As these problems are meant to be done without a calculator, calculating this further is cumbersome. The solution, however, states that since $35 = 5 \cdot 7$, then we only need to find $10^{5^{102}} \text{ mod } 7$. I can see (not immediately) the logic behind this. Basically, since $10^k$ is always divisible by $5$ for any sensical $k$, then:
$$10^k - r = 5(7)k$$
But then it's not immediately obvious how/why the fact that $5$ divides $10^k$ helps in this case.

My question is, is in general, if we have some mod system with $a^k \equiv r \text{ mod } m$ where $m$ can be decomposed into a product of numbers $a \times b \times c \ \times ...$, we only need to find the mod of those numbers where $a, b, c.....$ doesn't divides $a$? (And if this is the case why?) If this is not the case, then why/how is the solution justified in this specific instance?

Comment: How is $10 \equiv 1$ mod 7?

Comment: @Junglemath, idk....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mod of numbers with large exponents \[modular order reduction\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "logic" is that we can use a **mod distributive law** to pull out a common factor $\,\color{#c00}{c=5},\,$ i.e.

$$ \bbox[1px,border:3px solid #c60]{\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{\color{#c00}ca\bmod \color{#c00}cn\:\! =\, \color{#c00}c(a\bmod n)}} $$

This decreases the modulus from $\,cn\,$ to $\,n, \,$ simplifying modular arithmetic. Also it may eliminate CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem calculations, eliminating needless inverse computations, which are much more difficult than above for large numbers (or polynomials, e.g. see [this answer).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2104637/242)

This mod distributive law is often more convenient in congruence form, e.g.

$$ \ \ \bbox[1px,border:3px solid #c60]{\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00] {ca\equiv c(a\bmod n)\ \ \ {\rm if}\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{cn\equiv 0}\ \pmod{\! m}}}$$

since we have:  $\,\ c(a\bmod n) \equiv c(a\! +\! kn)\equiv ca+k(\color{#0a0}{cn})\equiv ca\pmod{\!m}$

e.g. in the OP: $\ \ I\ge 1\,\Rightarrow\, 10^{\large I+N}\!\equiv  10^{\large I}(10^{\large N}\!\bmod 7)\ \  {\rm by} \ \  10^I 7\equiv 0\pmod{\!35}$

Let's use that. [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) that exponents on $10$ can be reduced mod $\,6\,$ by little Fermat,

i.e. notice that $\ \color{#c00}{{\rm mod}\,\ 7}\!:\,\ 10^{\large 6}\equiv\, 1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{10^{\large 6J}\equiv 1}.\, $ So if $\ I \ge 1\ $ then as above

$\ \phantom{{\rm mod}\,\ 35\!:\,\ }\color{#90f}{10^{\large I+6J}}\!\equiv 10^{\large I} 10^{\large 6J}\!\equiv 10^{\large I}(\color{#c00}{10^{\large 6J}\!\bmod 7})\equiv  \color{#0a0}{10^{\large I}}\,\pmod{\!35} $

but $\ 5^{\large 102} = \color{#90f}{1\!+\!6J}\ $ by $\ {\rm mod}\,\ 6\!:\,\  5^{\large 102}\!\equiv (-1)^{\large 102}\!\equiv 1$

So $\ 10^{\large 5^{\large 102}}\!\! = \color{#90f}{10^{\large 1+6J}}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{10^{\large 1}} \pmod{\!35}\ $

---

**Remark** $\ $ For many more worked examples see the complete [list of linked questions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2059752?lq=1) Often this distributive law isn't invoked by name. Rather its trivial proof is repeated inline, e.g. from [a recent answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059369/242) using $\,cn = 14^2\cdot\color{#c00}{25}\equiv 0\pmod{100}$

$\begin{align}&\color{#c00}{{\rm mod}\ \ 25}\!:\ \  \ 14\equiv 8^{\large 2}\Rightarrow\, 14^{\large 10}\equiv \overbrace{8^{\large 20}\equiv 1}^{\rm\large  Euler\ \phi}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{14^{\large 10N}}\equiv\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\\[1em]
 &{\rm mod}\ 100\!:\,\ 14^{\large 2+10N}\equiv 14^{\large 2}\, \color{#0a0}{14^{\large 10N}}\! \equiv  14^{\large 2}\!\! \underbrace{(\color{#c00}{{\bf 1} + 25k})}_{\large\color{#0a0}{14^{\Large 10N}}\!\bmod{\color{#c00}{25}}}\!\!\! \equiv  14^{\large 2} \equiv\, 96\end{align}$

This distributive law is actually *equivalent* to CRT as we sketch below, with $\,m,n\,$ coprime

$\begin{align} x&\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}\\ \color{#c00}x&\equiv\color{#c00} b\!\!\!\pmod{\! n}\end{align}$
$\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!a\bmod mn\, =\, m\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}x-a}m\bmod n\right] = m\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}b-a}m\bmod n\right]$

which is exactly the same form solution given by [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242). But the *operational* form of this law often makes it much more convenient to apply in computations versus the classical CRT formula.

---

**Fractional extension**  of the mod distributive law: e.g. from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3979177/242)

notice:  $\,\ \ \dfrac{\color{#c00}{11}}{35}\bmod \color{#c00}{11}(9)\,=\, \color{#c00}{11}(\color{#0a0}8)\,$ by $\color{#0a0}{\bmod 9\!:\ \dfrac{1}{35}\equiv \dfrac{1}{-1}\equiv 8},\ $ by

**Theorem** $\ \ \dfrac{\color{#c00}ab}d\bmod \color{#c00}ac\, =\, \color{#c00}a\left(\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{b}d\bmod c}\right)\ \ $ **if** $\ \ (d,ac) = 1$

${\bf Proof}{\bf \:\!_1}\ $ [Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) & $(d,ac)\!=\!1 \Rightarrow$ exists $\, d' \equiv d^{-1}\!\pmod{\!ac}.\,$ Factoring out $\,\color{#c00}a\,$ by mDL

$\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \ \dfrac{\color{#c00}ab}d\bmod \color{#c00}ac \,=\,\color{#c00}abd'\bmod \color{#c00}ac\, =\ \color{#c00}a(bd'\bmod c) = \color{#c00}{a}\left( \dfrac{b}d\bmod c\right)$

by inverses *persist* at modulus factors:  $\ dd' \equiv 1\pmod{\!ac}\,\Rightarrow\, dd' \equiv 1\pmod{\!c}$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof\:\!_2}\qquad\qquad
\color{#0a0}x \,&\:\color{#0a0}{\equiv b/d \pmod c}\\[.2em]
\iff\ \ \ dx&\equiv b\ \ \ \ \pmod{c},\ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ (d,c)=1\\[.2em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\times\ a}\iff}\ \ dax&\equiv ab\ \ \pmod{ac}\\[.2em]
\iff\ \ \ \color{#c00}a\color{#0a0}x &\equiv \color{#c00}ab/d\!\!\!\pmod{\color{#c00}ac},\ \ {\rm by}\ \ (d,ac)=1
\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $10^{7}\equiv10^{1}\pmod{35}$.

Therefore $n>6\implies10^{n}\equiv10^{n-6}\pmod{35}$.

Let's calculate $5^{102}\bmod6$ using Euler's theorem:

- $\gcd(5,6)=1$
- Therefore $5^{\phi(6)}\equiv1\pmod{6}$
- $\phi(6)=\phi(2\cdot3)=(2-1)\cdot(3-1)=2$
- Therefore $\color\red{5^{2}}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{6}$
- Therefore $5^{102}\equiv5^{2\cdot51}\equiv(\color\red{5^{2}})^{51}\equiv\color\red{1}^{51}\equiv1\pmod{6}$

Therefore $10^{5^{102}}\equiv10^{5^{102}-6}\equiv10^{5^{102}-12}\equiv10^{5^{102}-18}\equiv\ldots\equiv10^{1}\equiv10\pmod{35}$.

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from your calculation:
$$\begin{align}
10^3&\equiv 6 \bmod 7 \\
&\equiv -1 \bmod 7 \\
\implies 10^6 = (10^3)^2&\equiv 1 \bmod 7
\end{align}$$
We could reach the same conclusion more quickly by observing that $7$ is prime so by Fermat's Little Theorem, $10^{(7-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

So we need to know the value of $5^{102}\bmod 6$, and here again $5\equiv -1 \bmod 6 $ so $5^{\text{even}}\equiv 1 \bmod 6$. (Again there are other ways to the same conclusion, but spotting $-1$ is often useful).

Thus $10^{\large 5^{102}}\equiv 10^{6k+1}\equiv 10^1\equiv 3 \bmod 7$.

Now the final step uses the Chinese remainder theorem for uniqueness of the solution (to congruence):
$$\left .\begin{align}
x&\equiv 0 \bmod 5 \\
x&\equiv 3 \bmod 7 \\
\end{align}
\right\}\implies x\equiv 10 \bmod 35 $$